# Rsyslog Central Log Host

Tags: rsyslog, syslog-ng

I'm moving from a syslog-ng central log host to rsyslog. I can't even seem to find syslog-ng in the CentOS repos these days. I want to filter logs by hostname and facility.

Here is how I do it in syslog-ng

```
destination std { 
    file("/var/log/HOSTS/$HOST/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/$FACILITY_$HOST_$YEAR_$MONTH_$DAY" 
        owner(root) group(root) perm(0600) dir_perm(0700) create_dirs(yes)
    ); 
};
```

Is there a simple way to do this with rsyslog?

Comment: FWIW: syslog-ng is still maintained and can be installed from EPEL. See http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/syslog-ng.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done via templates, like this:

```
$template HostDynFile,"/var/log/HOSTS/%HOSTNAME%/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%syslogfacility-text%_%HOSTNAME%_%$YEAR%_%$MONTH%_%$DAY%"
```

This template can then be used when defining an output selector line, e.g.:

```
*.* -?HostDynFile
```

More info is available here: [Building A Central Loghost On CentOS And RHEL 5 With rsyslog](http://www.howtoforge.com/building-a-central-loghost-on-centos-and-rhel-5-with-rsyslog)